# SharePoint 2010 Organization Browser limit active/enabled AD accounts users

Tags: user-profile-service, organization-browser

We are just starting to use the Organization browser webpart in our local intranet. While working with it we've noticed that disabled AD accounts are showing up in the list. Is there a way to filter the webpart to only bring back AD accounts that are enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could go to your user profile synchronization service to remove disabled accounts from the synchronization process.  [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brporter/archive/2010/02/20/excluding-disabled-user-accounts-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx) is where I found the solution.

1. Go to your central administration website
2. Click on "Application Management"
3. Click on "Manage Service Applications" under "Service Applications"
4. Click on the "User Profile Synchronization Service"
5. Click on "Configure Synchronization Connections" under "Synchronization"
6. Click on your connection and select "Edit Connection Filters" in the context menu
7. In the "Exclusion Filter for Users" section fill in "userAccountControl" for Attribute
8. Fill in "Bit on equals" for operator
9. Fill in "2" for filter
10. Click the "Add" button
11. Click the "OK" button at the bottom of the page